# Confirm Password Field is Always Equals to 1

Tags: php, html, passwords

I have a problem in registration form in my website
whatever i type in confirm password it convert it to one (I Knew it when I echo the password and Confirm Password)
and although the two values are different, it always gives me true when I compare between the password and the confirmation

here is the HTML:

```
<span><p>Password:</p>
<input type="password" size="25" name="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password"     style="margin-bottom:2ex;"  />
<font color="red">*</font>
<font color="grey">At least 8  characters.</font></span>
<span><p>Confirm Password:</p>
<input type="password" size="25" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Your Password" style="margin-bottom:2ex;"  />
<font color="red">*</font></span>
```

and here is my PHP Code

```
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
  if ($_POST['password'] != NULL && $_POST['confirm_password'] = !NULL) {
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

  if ($password != $confirm_password) {
  print ("<p><b><font color='red'>Provided passwords do not match</font></b></p>");
  } 

  else {
  $password = md5($password);
  //do the rest of code
  }
 }
}
```

---

UPDATE

There are some hidden part of the code, the submit button name is signup, and i checked that the values of the fields are not null
another thing
converting to one means that the value is always = 1

Comment: You don't have a named element called `signup` so your conditional statement will not work. Unless that's in an unshown part of your code. It's your submit button I'll bet, *right*? - Ah, knew it.

Comment: You need to verify that `password` and `confirm_password` are provided and not empty (and possibly some additional rules).

Comment: What do you mean "convert to one"?  The value actually changes?

Comment: Plus, you're using MD5 for password storage; **not** recommended.

Comment: If you do have that signup field as Fred asked, next question is: is the form even `POST`ing?

Comment: I answered all of your questions, sorry for not being clear..

Comment: You have `['confirm_password'] = !NULL)` that should be `!= NULL` tell me that's a typo. @user3504563

Comment: Fred !! Thank You !!!!! how silly that mistake was ! thank you so much, the problem is solved ! @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome. I posted an answer to close the question below. @user3504563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
if ($_POST['password'] != NULL && $_POST['confirm_password'] = !NULL) {
```

this `= !NULL` needs to be `!= NULL`

```
if ($_POST['password'] != NULL && $_POST['confirm_password'] != NULL) {
```

**Password storage:**

Consider using [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

- [**MD5**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is considered too fast and is outdated.